# IAC-protocol interface error on python 3

Tags: python-3.x, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I would like to work with excell sheets (.xls likely per .ods conversion) via python while maintaining all of the sheet's original content. Unlike ***xlutils*** (http://www.python-excel.org/) the ***iac-protocol*** (http://pythonhosted.org/iac-protocol/index.html) seems to me to be more fit/elegant tool to maintain sheet's style,formulas,dropboxes etc. One of the steps to launch iac's server or interpreter (iacs/iaci) is to initialize the interface which consists among others of this command:

**import iac.app.libreoffice.calc as localc**

While **import iac.app.libreoffice** works fine

moving to calc level 
**import iac.app.libreoffice.calc**
throws following error

> > > import iac.app.libreoffice.calc
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/iac/app/libreoffice/calc.py", line 11, in 
> > >           **from uno import getComponentContext
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name 'getComponentContext'**

From what I've learned so far on this forum it might be linked to method name duplicity between two modules. This is where I am stuck. How do I learn which other module has such name of a method and how to fix it? Both iac-protocol and unotools are modules downloaded via pip3. I did not created method of such name in any script.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

*Python3.4 on Scientific Linux release 7.3 (Nitrogen) LibreOffice 5.0.6.2 00(Build:2)*

Answer (score 0):

Some questions to narrow down the problem:

- Did you start libreoffice listening on a socket first?
- Did you import anything else before `import iac.app.libreoffice.calc`?
- What happens when you start python in a terminal and enter `from uno import getComponentContext`?

I installed iac-protocol on Linux Mint and was able to `import iac.app.libreoffice.calc` and then use it.  The installation process was complex, so I wouldn't be surprised if there is some problem with how your packages were installed, or possibly it does not work on RHEL-based systems.  For one thing, it required me to install gnumeric.

The Calc "Hello World" code that worked for me is as follows.

```
libreoffice "--accept=socket,host=localhost,port=18100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager" --norestore --nofirststartwizard --nologo --calc &
python3
>>> import iac.app.libreoffice.calc as localc
>>> doc = localc.Interface.current_document()
>>> sheet = doc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
>>> cell = sheet.getCellByPosition(0,0)
>>> cell.setString("Hello, World!")
```

One more thought: Have you considered using straight PyUNO starting from `import uno` instead of a wrapper library?  That would avoid dependency on some of the extra libraries which may be causing the problem.  Also there is [better documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) for straight PyUNO.

Comment: I did started the UNO bridge in the first place. A Calc sheet poped out as a response.
Prior "import iac.app.libreoffice.calc" command I imported only uno and iac ( and iac.app and so forth) with no issue.
 I was lucky to find libreoffice-pyuno library but the method getComponentContext is still missing.
I've found goffice library but I've had bad luck so far finding appropriate repository for gnumeric for RHEL 7. Should be part of EPEL (or EPEL- test) but I cannot find it.